# uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Ram and Shyam wanted to meet at a park about 12.30 P.M.. If Ram arrives at a time uniformly distributed between 12.15 P.M. to 12.45 P.M. and if Shyam independently arrives at a time uniformly distributed between 12.00 P.M. and 1.00 P.M., then find the probability that the first to arrive waits no longer than 5 minutes

Comment: similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218478/joint-pdf-of-uniformly-distributed-random-variables/1225450#1225450

Comment: An answer to a very similar problem can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxxrwZtpHH0&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60A3XMwZ5sep719_nh95qOe&index=4). Think how you can adapt this to your problem. Here the problem is solved in a geometric (visual) fashion, which is easy to get.

Comment: A friend who randomly arrives between 12 and 1 ... is not a friend you want. Hint: find a friend who can keep an appointment.

Comment: hi Pedro, the link you shared is very good but that is for continuous distribution and not uniform distribution.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first to arrive has to wait for no longer than 5 minutes then the condition would of wait time would become 0 to 5 minute.
Ram has to come from 12.15 to 12.45 
Shyam has to come from 12.10 to 12.50 to maintain wait time no longer than 5 minutes 
As per the rule of uniform distribution

```
      P = 1/(b-a). f(X) dx

     So sample space would be time from 12.10 P.M to 12.50 PM

     Therefore, a = 10, b = 5
                   P = 1/(50-10). f(X)

                  P =1/(40) . (0-5)

                  P = 5/40 = 1/8

                  Probability (P) = 1/8
```

Ans : So probability of first to arrive wait no longer than 5 minute would be 1/8.

Comment: Hi all, I would still like few comments on this solution. If it is accurate. Thanks